# Global NSString without alloc access only in 2 place or in two method and in 3rd place it crash the application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Here `NSString *documentsPath` declare in globally.

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Information.h"
@interface DetailViewController ()
{
    NSString *documentsPath;
    NSArray *paths;

}
```

assigning and accessing in viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Enter viewDidLoad DetailViewController");

   paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   **documentsPath** = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString *plistPath = [**documentsPath**  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"InfoDetail.plist"];
}
```

also accessing in `settingCellImage`  method

```
-(void)settingCellImage:(UITableViewCell *)cell noOfRow:(int)row
{
    NSLog(@"Enter in settingCellImage method");
    NSLog(@"Doc Path Cell ===>%@",documentsPath);

    NSString *imagePath = [**documentsPath** stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"/%d.png",row]];  
}
```

But when i use it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method it  crash the application.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Information *information = [[[Information alloc]initWithNibName:@"Information" bundle:nil]autorelease];

    information.infoDict = [test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Selected row No is ==> %d",indexPath.row);


    NSLog(@"Using @=== %d",indexPath.row);

    NSLog(@"documents path == %@",**documentsPath**);// here it gives EXE_BAD_ACCESS.

    NSString *selectedImagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.png",indexPath.row+1]];  

}
```

I'm new in iPhone development and it is my demo project. so please help me as soon as possible.
and please give me answer in easy way so i can understand very fast. And yes i know already that i'm not alloc `init` documentsPath direct assign in `viewDidLoad` method, and i want to know that why it will access in 2 places and in 3rd place it will crash the application. I hope someone  can help me. Thank you!

Comment: But why i am i don't want to create @property because i am not accessing that string in other class and i am not releasing that NSString object so why retain.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA just try it . i hope your problem solve using retain.

Comment: No i'm not using ARC.

Comment: The reason it crashes in third location is probably because that method executes on a different thread or at a later time and the memory has been released. If you aren't using a retain property then retain release aren't optional. It is the way memory management works

Comment: You can declare a private `@property` without having to make it public, just do it in a class extension at the beginning of your .m, before the `@implementation`.

Comment: You'll save yourself and the maintainer of your code a lot of headaches if you start instance variables with an underscore, like everyone else does. That makes it clear to the reader when you are accessing instance variables and not properties, and it makes it clear to yourself as well. Especially if you don't use ARC; improper use of instance variables instead of properties is going to kill you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

documentsPath has static assign  and then i manipulate it with stringByAppendingFormat it creates problem because documentsPath is a immutable and then also you are manipulate it so the application is crash. so the manipulations of immutable object generate problem.Because NSString object by default immutable object you can not change or manipulate assigned string.

Try This instead of  when you want to use stringByAppendingFormat .

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%d.png", documentsPath,indexPath.row+1];
```

Use NSString initWithFormat and don't manipulate String.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using ARC, you have to make sure you are retain/releasing/autoreleasing all your objects. What's happening is that your documentsPath got released and now you are accessing a released object. You could assign the string like so:

```
documentsPath = [[NSString stringWithString:[paths objectAtIndex:0]] retain];
```

And then you have to release it in your dealloc call.

Comment: Check now; I edited it after I found out that you are not using ARC.

Comment: Minor enhancement: You should always `copy` NSStrings.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe agreed. Updated code to create a new instance of string.

Comment: @jancakes and Nikolai Ruhe You both right i understand your answers. In this the object is autometic garbage collected means it is by default autorelease object so the scope is not specified. Right Guys?

Comment: iOS doesn't do Garbage Collection, but if you use ARC, then retain/release/autorelease is inserted for you automatically and memory management is taken care of for you. When you are not using ARC, you have to do all the retaining/releasing yourself. Since you didn't call alloc or copy or retain on documentsPath, you weren't increasing its retain count and therefore weren't the owner of that object.

Comment: Here's some more on memory management: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you use **stringByAppendingFormat** two times for **documentsPath** and then at **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** when you access to it. App will crash.

Comment: sorry @lee now i understand that documentsPath  is static assign and then i will modify it by stringByAppendingFormat so that's why it creates problem .thank You lee!

Answer (score 0):

Use ARC.

Even if you do use ARC, you should understand the basics of object ownership. Do a search on "Basic Memory Management Rules" in Xcode and read that entire section. Also read the section below, "Practical Memory Management"

To summarize, if you need an object to stick around, you need to retain it/maintain a strong reference to it. Every retain needs to be balanced with a release. This means that when you are done with an object that you have retained, you must release it.

Your code is not following those rules, so you're crashing.

Comment: Thank you! for giving me some knowledge about memory management.